# Exiting from outer calling functions on error

Tags: error-handling

Consider the following:

```
(defun my-divide-by-0()
  (condition-case nil
      (/ 1 0)
    (error (progn (message "Could not evaluate: 1/0") nil))))

(defun my-test()
  (interactive)
  (my-divide-by-0)
  (message "Continued"))
```

When I do `M-x my-test`, the message `Continued` appears. How do I modify the error handling in `my-divide-by-0` so only the message `Could not evaluate: 1/0` would appear and the execution of my program would stop without the necessity to check error conditions in `my-test`? I tried throwing, but then the message `Arithmetic error` appears...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't raise an error with your error message. You just used `message`.

So your message actually appeared (check buffer `*Messages*`), but then execution continued and the second message was displayed.

If you want to stop execution when the error occurs then you need to raise another error.  E.g.:

```el
(defun my-divide-by-0 ()
  (condition-case nil
      (/ 1 0)
    (error (error "Could not evaluate: 1/0"))))
```

And if you want to see the original error message as part of your error message then you need to use a variable in place of `nil`:

`(condition-case err-var...)`, not `(condition-case nil...)`.

And then raise an error with a message that combines whatever message you want with the original message:

```el
(defun my-divide-by-0 ()
  (condition-case err-var
      (/ 1 0)
    (arith-error (error "Could not evaluate: 1/0, %s" (error-message-string err-var)))))
```

`C-h f condition-case` tells you:

> When a handler handles an error, control returns to the `condition-case`
>   and it executes the handler's `BODY...`
>   with `VAR` bound to `(ERROR-SYMBOL . SIGNAL-DATA)` from the error.
>   **(If `VAR` is `nil`, the handler can't access that information.)**
>
> Then the value of the last `BODY` form is returned from the `condition-case`
>   expression.

Comment: I do not see how this answers my question. How does using `ERR-VAL` help me quit the command on error?

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer. Hopefully it is more helpful now.

Comment: Although I still do not get what happens when I raise an error twice, it does what I need!

Comment: The error is raised by division by zero. But you have a handler that intercepts it, prevent it from being raised to the user. Your handler then raises a different error (which presumably is not handled), showing the message you prefer.

Comment: If you want not to raise an error at all, but just to be sure that your message is shown for a while, before the second message appears, then you can use `sleep-for` after the `message` call, inside the error handler. It all depends on what behavior you want.

Comment: The first (the outside one?) `error` is a handler of the exception raised by the division. The second `error` is to raise an additional exception. So, is `error` a handler or a raiser?

Comment: The symbol `error` has two uses here. *Function* `error` raises an error. Inside `condition-case`, the symbol `error` is not the *function* `error`; it just introduces a (general) error handler. In this context, `error` is "*condition name `error` which takes in all kinds of errors*". See the Elisp manual, node [Error Symbols](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Symbols.html).